# Backbone - Limiting Number of Items to Show in a Collection

Tags: collections, backbone.js, limit, mustache

I have a dropdown box which will change number of items of a collection to be displayed on the page...

```
{{#each myCollection}}
<div id="{{this.Name}}">{{this.Name}} </div>
{/each}}
<select id="ddpFilter" >
<option value="10">Show 10</option>
<option value="50">Show 50</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you can put it in a forloop then use this.collection.at(loopIndex) to get the model.

Comment: just limit the number of items you send to the template. don't send the whole collection.

Comment: Thank you for the responses.. I think i am getting it...
The render method will show the whole 20 items... When I select show 10 items, i will update the collection but only send 10 items.. how do i do this on the fly? I understand that there are listener methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [first()](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#first) Underscore method [baked into Backbone Collections](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods).  Here's an example of how you might combine `first()` with your template:

```
Backbone.View.extend({

  // Number of items to show from the collection.  Set this and re-render when you 
  // want to show 50.
  limit: 10, 

  // Notice I switched myCollection to items.  Backbone collections aren't directly
  // iterable, but their underscore methods (like first(n)) return vanilla 
  // iterable Arrays
  template: Handlebars.compile("{{#each items}} {{this.Name}} {/each}}"),

  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template({
      // Pass a truncated Array into the template to keep it logicless and Mustachy
      items: myCollection.first(this.limit)
    }));
  }
});
```